# Unsure about instanceof a Function

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var myObject = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    return this;
};

myObject.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
console.log(myObject instanceof Function); // true
</script>
```

Question:

How to understand this line: `console.log(myObject instanceof Function); // true`? If we want to make instance, we need to use `new` keyword, right? something like: `var myObject = new Function();` so how could myObject be the instance of Function?

Comment: You didn't use `new` anywhere. `myObject` **is** the constructor function.

Comment: Incidentally, the constructor doesn't need `return this`, it will return the new object by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myObject` is a function, every function is an instance of `Function`.

```
console.log(myObject instanceof Function); // true
console.log(new myObject('foo') instanceof myObject); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

> If we want to make instance, we need to use new keyword, right?

Usually. Function expressions also return function objects though.